# How to get two sums of number of fields from a list of names: one with 2 fields, the other with 3 or more?

Tags: bash, scripting, awk

I want to figure out how to sort a list of names (FS=" ") into two piles: one with 2 fields, and the other with 3 + fields, but only show the total number of records in both lists in one sentence. Is this even possible? If so, how?

(I am new to awk, scripting. There are loads of info regarding how to show sums of fields, but not how to split up a list into two files by NF and then show the sum.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here goes

```
awk 'NF >= 2{x[NF==2?2:3]++};
END{for (i in x) printf "%d records with %s fields\n", x[i], i==3?"3+":"2"}' file
```

Comment: @Müt, the driver is the array `x`, which is a running counter. Notice that the key is `2` for those cases where (obviously) the number of fields is `2`. Whenever the number of fields is more than `2`, the count is stored against a key value of `3`. `NF >= 2` the filter condition ensures that all this logic only kicks in when the number of fields is `2` or more!

Comment: Certain awk versions need parentheses to avoid ambiguity: `(i==3?"3+":"2")`

Comment: I could be shortened a little still perhaps by using `awk 'NF >= 2{x[NF==2?2:"3+"]++}` ..

Comment: Scrutinizer - are you saying that your shortcut can replace the first line of 1_CR's solution? (I'm guessing not the whole thing as I do want to output the actual sums in a succint statement)...

Comment: also, while on the topic.....does anyone know if there's a way to produce the same totals without the \n (and  without having to resort to printf, and instead use only plain old print}? (as shown above)

Comment: @Müt Yes, I mean: `awk 'NF >= 2{x[NF>2?"3+":2]++};
END{for (i in x) printf "%d records with %s fields\n", x[i], i}'`

Comment: @Müt: Without printf and "\n" that would be something like: `END{for (i in x) print x[i], "records with", i, "fields"}'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming numbers are in the last field

```
awk '{ sum += $NF } END { print sum }' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I guess I failed to explain my issue clearly or (I'm not understanding?)- the list is composed of people's names- some have first and last (2 fields), and the rest have nicknames, middle names, suffixes, etc. (hence, 3 or more fields). I want to get a total number of people who have only first and last names listed, and total sum of people who have chosen to insert extraneous names, nicknames, etc. my output would be something like, "listof2names: 286  and listof3+names: 378."

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your input?

Comment: Thanks Amit - not sure if still interested since the question is already answered, but a sample would be: George Smith \n Jane M. Jones \n Mark "Slug" Hamhocks, Jr. \n Mel Li So, basically, George and Mel are the only two with 2 names (first and last), and the others have either a mid initial, suffix, nickname attached. I wanted to separate those who had only first and last names,  and those who had extraneous "fields" to their names. In short, instead of the usual 'get sum of such and such fields, this was, instead, a sorting and gathering of the sums of FS's (or NF's depending on approach).